# Inserting floats into New Dataframe and getting NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to insert a series of floats into a new Dataframe (for future manipulation and for easier visual comparison of values). The code runs without error, and the table is output, but my floats come up as NaN. If I print the float, the correct number is output, so I know the number exists.

This is what the floats look like (there are many more of them):

```
total_pressure_at_100_for_80 = tem80df['pressure80'][0:103].sum() 
total_pressure_at_100_for_100= tem100df['pressure100'][0:103].sum()
```

They're just the sum of a column(pressure##) in a dataframe (tem##) and I'm trying to sum the first 103 rows. I just want to insert the value of the sum into a new Dataframe. This is what I've got:

```
data = {'Depth used for calculation': ['80','100', '120', '140', '160','180'],
        'Data from tem80': [total_pressure_at_80_for_80, total_pressure_at_100_for_80, total_pressure_at_120_for_80, total_pressure_at_140_for_80, total_pressure_at_160_for_80, total_pressure_at_180_for_80]}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Depth used for calculation', ' Data from tem80'])
print(df)
```

This is what I get:

```
  Depth used for calculation  Data from tem80
0                         80              NaN
1                        100              NaN
2                        120              NaN
3                        140              NaN
4                        160              NaN
5                        180              NaN
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is typo `' Data from tem80'` remove space.

Comment: Or better use only `df = pd.DataFrame (data)`

Comment: Extra tip : I always avoid using spaces at column names. I suggest you to do the same.